# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: "InvalidRequestError: Unrecognized request argument supplied"

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, gpt-3

```
import openai

# Set the API key
openai.api_key = "YOUR API KEY"

# Define the conversation memory
conversation_memory = {
    "previous_question": "What is the capital of France?",
    "previous_answer": "The capital of France is Paris."
}

# Make the API request
response = openai.Completion.create(
    model="text-davinci-003",
    prompt="Where is the Eiffel Tower located?",
    temperature=0.5,
    max_tokens=1024,
    top_p=1,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0,
    conversation_memory=conversation_memory
)

# Print the response
print(response.text)
```

Why the conversation_memory  parameter not being recognize. I try this with serveral different models and they all give me the same error. I have the lastest OpenAi on my computer. I don't understand.

Here the error:

```
     InvalidRequestError                       Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-17-ace11d6ce405> in <module>      11      12 # Make the API request ---> 13 response = openai.Completion.create(      14     model="text-babbage-001",      15     prompt="Where is the Eiffel Tower located?", C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\completion.py in create(cls, *args, **kwargs)      23 while True:      24 try: ---> 25 return super().create(*args, **kwargs)      26 except TryAgain as e:      27 if timeout is not None and time.time() > start + timeout: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py in create(cls, api_key, api_base, api_type, request_id, api_version, organization, **params)     113         )     114         url = cls.class_url(engine, api_type, api_version) --> 115         response, _, api_key = requestor.request(     116 "post",     117             url, C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py in request(self, method, url, params, headers, files, stream, request_id, request_timeout)     179             request_timeout=request_timeout,     180         ) --> 181 resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)     182 return resp, got_stream, self.api_key     183 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py in _interpret_response(self, result, stream)     394 else:     395             return ( --> 396                 self._interpret_response_line(     397                     result.content, result.status_code, result.headers, stream=False     398                 ),  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py in _interpret_response_line(self, rbody, rcode, rheaders, stream)     427         stream_error = stream and "error" in resp.data     428 if stream_error or not 200 <= rcode < 300: --> 429             raise self.handle_error_response(     430                 rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders, stream_error=stream_error     431             ) 
 InvalidRequestError: Unrecognized request argument supplied: conversation_memory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error itself tells you what's wrong.

**You're trying to pass `conversation_memory` as a parameter to the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) endpoint, which is not a valid parameter.**

See the [complete list](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create) of parameters you can pass to the Completions API endpoint:

- `model`
- `prompt`
- `suffix`
- `max_tokens`
- `temperature`
- `top_p`
- `n`
- `stream`
- `logprobs`
- `echo`
- `stop`
- `presence_penalty`
- `frequency_penalty`
- `best_of`
- `logit_bias`
- `user`