# Openai Context related questions consultation

Tags: openai-api

I can return the dialogue information normally through openai's text-davinci-003, but the context correlation function cannot be realized at present.
I searched and found that there is a "conversation_id" parameter, but after adding the parameter, the API returns "Unrecognized request argument supplied: conversation_id".
I would like to inquire if this feature requires paying users to use it. I am currently a free test user.

I searched and found that there is a "conversation_id" parameter, but after adding the parameter, the API returns "Unrecognized request argument supplied: conversation_id".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is conversation\_memory not being recognized by the OpenAI API (InvalidRequestError: Unrecognized request argument supplied)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74978793/why-is-conversation-memory-not-being-recognized-by-the-openai-api-invalidreques)

Comment: It has nothing to do with you being a free test user. You cannot pass `conversation_id` as a parameter to the Completions endpoint (see my answer to the question in the comment above).

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in the comments, `conversation_id` is not a valid input parameter, you can see the valid parameters in the API reference: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create